# Add to HomeScreen(progressive web app)?

Tags: angular

Browser should ask you want to add banner on home screen yes/no? 
I use service worker with beforepromt event which is used to invoke browser api for banner display but still dont work.It is work manually.I want that banner show automatically when user hit on that web app.